# Merge N sorted in vectors c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a vector of sorted c++ classes that have comparison operators.  I need a vector of the objects sorted.  Is there any open source algorithms that would take either a list of vectors or vector of vectors and make one sorted vector?

for n=2, this works fine:

```
std::vector<Data> dst;
std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));
```

Comment: if you can merge 2 vectors, what is the problem to merge n vectors?

Comment: Just do the above in a loop with `v[i]` and `v[i+1]` instead, won't it work?

Comment: I have 300 vectors to merge  that have 50000 data points each.

Comment: This will get run constantly and I would like to keep O(n)

Comment: I guess I can just merge  in a loop

Comment: And?  There is no magic solution.  You have to touch every element in every vector.  Get a accumulator vector, reserve the appropriate space and then loop through them all merging them into the accumulator.

Comment: will do.  Thank you

Comment: @NathanOliver Successive merging will work, but, especially for larger numbers of sequences, there are lower-complexity solutions.

Comment: @AmiTavory Your right.  Successive mergers would be O(n^2)(?) which is too much.  Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's understandable, as usually the total merged sequence size is much larger than the number of sequences (so they're usually thought of as a constant). Still, since a function of the number of sequences multiplies the total sequence size, it pays to reduce it, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library contains the [`merge` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), allowing to merge two sorted vectors (in particular).

Say you have *k* sequences, with total length *n*. Of course, you could merge each time 2 sequences until only a single one remains, but this is [known to be worst-case Θ(k<sup>2</sup>n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Non-optimal).

There are two alternatives:

- *Merging By Greedy Size* In this variant, each time, the two shortest sequences are merged. This [reduces the worst-case time to [*Θ(k log(k) n)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#optimal_merge_pattern).
- *Merging With A Priority Queue* In [this scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Binary_Tree_Implementation), a priority queue holds pairs of iterators and sequence indices, when a smallest element is popped, the next item from the sequence with this index is pushed. This has time *Θ(log(k) n)*, as the priority queue has at most *k* items at each time.

The following contains an implementation of the latter (with the full code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/h2LfZc)). (I suspect that, while asymptotically better than the former, it has much higher constants than the former. A generic implementation of the greedy algorithm is (at least for me) a bit trickier, though.)

```
include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>


template<
    class InIts, 
    typename OutIt,
    class Cmp=std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<typename InIts::value_type::first_type>::value_type>>
OutIt merge(const InIts &in_its, OutIt out_it, Cmp cmp=Cmp())
{
    using it_t = typename InIts::value_type::first_type;
    using pair_t = std::pair<it_t, std::size_t>;
    auto pair_cmp = [cmp](const pair_t &lhs, const pair_t &rhs) { return !cmp(*lhs.first, *rhs.first); };
    using q_t = std::priority_queue<pair_t, std::vector<pair_t>, decltype(pair_cmp)>;

    std::vector<std::pair<it_t, it_t>> origs{in_its};
    q_t q{pair_cmp};

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < origs.size(); ++i)
    {   
        auto &p = origs[i];
        if(p.first != p.second)
            q.push(std::make_pair(p.first++, i));
    }

    while(!q.empty()) 
    {
        auto t = q.top();
        *(out_it++) = *t.first;
        const auto i = t.second;
        q.pop();

        auto &p = origs[i];
        if(p.first != p.second)
            q.push(std::make_pair(p.first++, i));
    }

    return out_it;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    using vec_t = std::vector<int>;

    vec_t v0{1, 2, 3}; 
    vec_t v1{2, 3, 4}; 
    vec_t v2{4, 5, 6}; 

    using vec_it_t = vec_t::iterator;

    std::vector<std::pair<vec_it_t, vec_it_t>> its{
        std::make_pair(std::begin(v0), std::end(v0)),
        std::make_pair(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)),
        std::make_pair(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2))};

    vec_t res;
    merge(its, std::back_inserter(res));
    for(auto &e: res)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The priority queue implementation should be O(n*logk), no?

Comment: @interjay Many thanks - you're absolutely right (corrected).

Comment: I think the other algorithm should have the same complexity as well. When the Wikipedia article you linked says `O(n*k*logk)`, I think that they consider `n` to be the size of each list rather than the total size.

Comment: @interjay Thanks again for the comment. Not sure I agree, but it might be the late hour. Will look into it tomorrow.